# Single breaker for 2 devices

Tags: circuit-protection

I am working on a project and trying to figure out the appropriate circuit protection scheme. We have 2 AC/DC battery chargers that will be housed in a single enclosure, being powered off 220VAC. Meanwell DBU-3200. The spec sheet says AC current typical 17A, inrush current typical 55A. I'm not familiar with best practices here, but it seems like a breaker at the line input to feed these devices would make sense. But what value? Should it be a single breaker? Or 1 upstream breaker and then 2 individual downstream breakers? I'm assuming any breaker used should be 2-pole? Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: A licensed electrician would know the answer to your problems.  Call one, and pay for their services.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I was questioning whether that would be the right person to get an opinion from, but since this is internal to a single enclosure (which probably wasn't clear in my post) I thought it might fall more on the EE side.

Comment: Remember that the breaker is not specified just to protect your battery chargers, it is intended to protect all of the wiring in your product. Don't use a breaker with a higher current rating than the **minimum** safe current for **any** wire, connector, or switch in your system.

Comment: In that case, @ElliotAlderson has the best point.  Along with local codes and regs.

Comment: Thanks @ElliotAlderson That makes sense to make sure all wires/connectors/etc must be rated for at least the breaker rating. So we can make sure we use appropriately sized accompanying components. But, would a 50A breaker, for example, be sufficient to protect these units in parallel? Or would it make more sense to use individual breakers for the 2 units?

Comment: Protect them from **what**? Why would you use a 50A breaker if the inrush current is 55A?

Comment: You need a specific breaker that allows inrush current but still breaks if it is over the rating for some period of time (usually a few milliseconds). You need to determine how long the inrush lasts for and find a breaker profile that matches. These are called "curves" and you probably want a 20A B-Curve breaker for the 17A load, or a 40A B-Curve for both if they share a line (provided the line components are rated above that).

Comment: Good question @ElliotAlderson This sounds like a silly answer, but, protect them from whatever one typically uses a breaker for? As far as I'm aware, this is to prevent fires, essentially. And I say 50A because I was advised once to use a breaker for at least 25% more than the typical draw. 17A x 2 x 1.25 = 42.5A, then I rounded up. The inrush should be very briefly and not long enough to trip the breaker.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer That makes a lot of sense on the timing. If a 20A B-curve breaker would work for 1 unit, could a 40A or 50A B-curve breaker work for 2 units?

Comment: No, you need to actually think about what kind of fault you are worried about. Assuming that you are connecting this to electrical service that was properly installed there must already be a breaker that prevents excessive branch currents. So what **exact** part of your system are you trying to protect and what **exact** fault are you worried about?

Comment: The circuit breaker is determined upon your installation wiring. If you wan't to use 50A breaker, the wires may not be less than approx. 16mm^2. It depends on how many wires, wall placing, air,...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I must admit, I can't say exactly I'm worried about, other than following best practices. I suppose it's some overcurrent situation in the chargers. A short circuit would be detected by any breaker, but could there be some failure where it's drawing 30A (instead of the spec'd 17A) and operating improperly? This is something a 50A breaker would not catch. So, I suppose I should have asked for guidance on best practices for protection of AC devices?

Comment: I am almost 100% that this PSU has its own fuse inside, not for malfunction protection, rather for fire protection. Wha you need is 20A  fuse in the cabinet for each device and 4mm^2 copper wires - double, for each device.separately.

Comment: That's a good point, @MarkoBuršič I just popped the end off of one of these and there it is! But why would we need another fuse inline with this one, external to the charger?